# call web service through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

i just want to call web service through jquery ajax.. i hv made a web service method which show us Current date time of the system.. but my program couldn't work properly may be some error arise in when i put url of webservice.. if you check my code it would be appreciate able.. i just hope for the best

here My Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()

  {

       $("#btn").click(function() 
         {
            $.ajax(
            {
              type:"POST",
              url:"Service.asmx/CurrentTime",
              data:"{}",
              contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(msg)
                 {
                   $("#show").text(msg.d);
                 }

                      });

                      });

                        });
```

My web service Code:

```
       using System;

       using System.Collections.Generic;

       using System.Linq;

       using System.Web;

       using System.Web.Services;

       namespace WebService1

          {

              [WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]

              [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

              [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

              [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

              public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
                 {


                     [WebMethod]
                     public string CurrentTime()
                            {
                                return DateTime.Now.ToString();
                             }
                     }
                     }
```

Still i didn't get solution for this...????????

Comment: `data:"{}",` either try removing it or use this way: `data:{}`,

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: i didn't get any error.. that's why i m confused... i didn't pass any parameter in data

Comment: @user3193071 you have not included the `error: function(){}` callback. use this to get the errors.

Comment: Anyone here who give me the best solution..after that i wud run my code perfectly..????

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"Service.asmx/CurrentTime",
     dataType : 'text',  //<------since your controller returns string use "text"
     success: function(msg){
         $("#show").text(msg);
     },
     error: function(xhr){  //<----use this callback to get the xhr errors
        console.log(xhr);
     }
});
```

#### Note:

Since your controller return type is not `json`  so don't use `dataType : json and contentType` instead you can use dataType as `text` as suggested in the answer. Also in your success function you can put your data in the desired element as suggested.

Comment: i used 'text' in datatype instead of 'json' but still its not working

Comment: Hey jai i used ur whole code but bro.. but still its not working in fact its not showing any error

Comment: are you able to debug in chrome inspector? if your browser is chrome then check the network tab and see if your webservice is getting called there.

Comment: [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: That was my mistake that should be as it is now.

Comment: I have Already uncomment that line but still its not working... please help me to get my code runable.. it would be appreciate.. i just hope for answer

Comment: @Ammi [see this page if you get something out of it.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm)